# AFNetworkReachabilityManager can't detect Active Internet Connection

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-3

I'm using AFNetworkReachabilityManager to check status of internet connection.
It works fine for following cases:

`Wifi is turned 'ON'`

`Wifi is turned 'OFF'`

But when user is `connected to a wifi network without active internet connection`
it still returns status as 'reachable'

```
 self.manager = [AFNetworkReachabilityManager managerForDomain:@"https://www.google.com"];
[self.manager setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status)
 {
         if (status == AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable)
         {
            [weakSelf.statusLabel setText:@"Not Connected"];
        }
        else
        {
            [weakSelf.statusLabel setText:@"Connected"];
        }
}];
```

Comment: which ios version ?

Comment: version is ios 9.3.4

Comment: okay, so is that really you need to check you wifi status with `AFNetworking` are you free to use `reachablity` ?

Comment: i can use `reachability` but I found AFNetworking more easy to use

Comment: ok so as you feel comfort you can go with that, if you can switch i can provide a small working method using `reachablity`.

Comment: @vaibhav i wanted to do it with AFNetworking , can you suggest why it is not working ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125717/discussion-between-vaibhav-and-sandeepaggarwal).